# SQL Join three tables

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm learning advanced SQL queries little by little and I'm fairly stumped with a problem:

I have three tables: `news`, `author`, and `images`. Each field in the `news` table (`newsID`) is a news story, which then has an associated author in the `author` table (`authorID`) and can have any number of images associated in the `images` table. Each image has and associated (`newsID`). So each story has one author but can have several images.

I want to make a list of all news stories and use *just one* of the images as a thumbnail image. The problem is that any sql query I try to list the `news` items with gives me results equal to the number of images in the `images` table rather than the number of `news` items.

I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use `LIMIT 1` to get just the first image.

Comment: Can you specify which database are you trying this on and the schema of your tables?

Comment: @Kerrek "Limit" only works with a specific flavor of database

Answer (score 21):

If the 3 tables in question are [*news*], [*author*] and [*image*] with appropriate columns, then

**Derived Table approach**

you can have a derived image table to get one image per news and then join it with the *news* and *author* table as shown.
This has been written and tested in SQL Server.

```
SELECT  
      N.[newsStoryTitle]
        ,A.authorName
        ,I.imageData1
  FROM [news] N
  LEFT OUTER JOIN author A ON A.newsID = N.newsID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT newsID, MAX(imageData) AS imageData1 FROM [image] 
    GROUP BY newsID
    )  AS I ON I.newsID = N.newsID
ORDER BY N.newsID
```

You could replace the LEFT OUTER JOINs with INNER JOINs if you do not need news without any images.

**Correlated Subquery approach** (as suggested by Marcelo Cantos)

If the imageData is stored as a text or image, then the MAX in the derived table wouldn't work. In that case, you can use a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT  N.newsStoryTitle ,
        A.authorName ,
        I.imageData
FROM    dbo.news N
        INNER JOIN dbo.author A ON N.newsID = A.newsID
        INNER JOIN dbo.image I ON N.newsID = I.newsID
WHERE   imageID = ( SELECT  MAX(imageID)
                    FROM    dbo.image
                    WHERE   newsID = N.newsID
                  )
ORDER BY n.newsID
```

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: This is called a "derived table"

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add the following predicate:

```
FROM news JOIN images ...
...
WHERE imageID = (SELECT MAX(imageID)
                   FROM image
                  WHERE newsID = news.newsID)
```

Note that this excludes news items without an image. If you don't want this, you'll need a left join on images and an additional condition on the WHERE:

```
FROM news LEFT JOIN images ...
...
WHERE imageID IS NULL
   OR imageID = (SELECT MAX(imageID)
                   FROM image
                  WHERE newsID = news.newsID)
```

Comment: Does it matter if it is imageID = (SELECT ...) vs. imageID in (SELECT ...)

Comment: this would not work because the where clause always gives one value and hence there would be only one row from news.

Comment: @Kash: It's a correlated subquery. It will yield one row per news item, which is, AFAICT, the intent.

Comment: @Daryl: If you make a mistake in the subquery and it returns more than one row, `in` will blissfully return duplicate news items. The `=` option will crash noisily, alerting you to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can to modify the order by on the subselect to get the 1 image per news row you are looking for...

```
select
....
from news n
left outer join images i on i.imageID = (
    select top 1 i2.imageID 
    from images i2 
    where i2.newsID = n.newsID
    order by --??
)
```

Comment: Still no luck. I'm not getting the result set I want. I'll have to rethink this. Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: maybe recheck you're using the table aliases in the right spot...`i` vs `i2`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 table in mysql and you want to join it together. for example I have 3 table 
1 student
2 subject
3 score
now want to join student with subject and score. so we you this syntax :
select * from student inner join subject inner join score;